Problem with downloadAsync expo with react native App using SQLite DB
I am trying to create/copy a database from the one in my assets to the Iphones documents directory with Expo filesystem. Here is my code:
import React, { useState, useEffect, Suspense } from "react";
import { View, ActivityIndicator, Text, Alert } from "react-native";
import { TabBarVisibilityProvider } from "../context/TabBarVisibilityContext";
import { SQLiteProvider } from "expo-sqlite";
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
import { Asset } from "expo-asset";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

const loadDatabase = async () => {
  const dbName = "mySQLiteDB.db";
  const dbAsset = require("../assets/mySQLiteDB.db");
  const dbUri = Asset.fromModule(dbAsset).localUri;
  const dbFilePath = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/${dbName}`;

  const fileInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(dbFilePath);
  if (!fileInfo.exists) {
    await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(
      `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite`,
      { intermediates: true }
    );
    await FileSystem.downloadAsync(dbUri, dbFilePath);
  }
};

const RootLayout = () => {
  const [dbLoaded, setDbLoaded] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    loadDatabase()
      .then(() => setDbLoaded(true))
      .catch((e) => console.error(e));
  }, []);
  const [fontsLoaded, error] = useFonts({
    "SNPro-Black": require("../assets/fonts/SNPro-Black.otf"),
    "Inknut-Antiqua-Bold": require("../assets/fonts/InknutAntiqua-Bold.ttf"),
    "SNPro-Bold": require("../assets/fonts/SNPro-Bold.otf"),
    "SNPro-Light": require("../assets/fonts/SNPro-Light.otf"),
    "SNPro-Medium": require("../assets/fonts/SNPro-Medium.otf"),
    "SNPro-Regular": require("../assets/fonts/SNPro-Regular.otf"),
    "SNPro-Thin": require("../assets/fonts/SNPro-Thin.otf"),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
    if (fontsLoaded) SplashScreen.hideAsync();
  }, [fontsLoaded, error]);
  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  if (!fontsLoaded && !error) return null;

  if (!dbLoaded)
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size={"large"} />
        <Text>Loading Database...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  return (
    <TabBarVisibilityProvider>
      <GestureHandlerRootView>
        <React.Suspense
          fallback={
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <ActivityIndicator size={"large"} />
              <Text>Loading Database...</Text>
            </View>
          }
        >
          <SQLiteProvider databaseName="mySQLiteDB.db" useSuspense>
            <Stack>
              <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            </Stack>
          </SQLiteProvider>
        </React.Suspense>
      </GestureHandlerRootView>
    </TabBarVisibilityProvider>
  );
};

export default RootLayout;


When I load this to my Iphone and try opening the app it loads the database for ever. I implemented a try and catch inside the loaddatabase function and it displayed an error of: calling the downloadasync function failed caused by file '/' is not readable.
When I load the code to my Iphone and try opening the app it loads the database for ever. I implemented a try and catch inside the loaddatabase function and it displayed an error of: calling the downloadasync function failed caused by file '/' is not readable.
